# How can I join 'user_id' in a BigQuery table with 'user_id' in a Firebase Auth table to retrieve associated email addresses?

Tags: google-bigquery, firebase-authentication

I have a BigQuery table named event_log that contains a field user_id. I also have a Firebase Auth project which contains my registered users. Entries in the BigQuery table are added from a flask API.

Here is a simplified example data for the BigQuery table, where user_id is the user_uid that firebase assigns to each user when they register:

| user_id | event_type |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | click |
| 456 | view |

My goal is to be able to write a query in BigQuery that joins these two tables on the user_id field to create a single table that includes both the user_id and corresponding email address from Firebase so I can see which users did what without having to manually check the user_id in the firebase console.

I'm not sure how to do this, or if it is even possible. I've tried setting up the BigQuery integration in Firebase, but I don't actually think it provides this kind of access to the firebase user auth table. Or perhaps I set it up incorrectly.

Is this possible? If so, how would I write the query in BigQuery. I could write an endpoint in my API to query both and send the response back, but would much rather be able to do it directly in bigquery console.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to set up your own `users` table in BigQuery, so that you can join it with the `events` data. To populate that data, you can use the Firebase Admin SDK to [list all users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users) or use the command-line interface to [export all users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth#auth-export), and then import that into BigQuery.

Comment: Ah cool thanks. This is what I was hoping to avoid, duplicating user data into BQ and keeping it up to date all the time. But if there's no way to join directly with FB using the BQ integration, then I'll give this a go instead :)